# Angular 9 - Trying to iterate through a list of objects and validate

Tags: json, angular, typescript

apologies if this is a really basic question but I'm just starting out with angular 9 and json.
I'm trying to iterate through a list and only create a line for the table if the correct ID is matched with the ID that is passed through from previous page link

I'm trying to get the if statement working in the for loop but it isn't producing anything.

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let tag of tags; if tag.id == tagged.id">
      <th>{{ tag.id }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.manufacturer }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.serial }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.inspectedDate }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.result }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.actionNeeded }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.inspectee }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.certificateNumb }}</th>
      <th>{{ tag.nextInspection }}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I can get it to work if I do the following code but I know this is not optimal and I can't find/figure out the correct way

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let tag of tags">
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.id }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.manufacturer }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.serial }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.inspectedDate }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.result }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.actionNeeded }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.inspectee }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.certificateNumb }}</th>
      <th *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">{{ tag.nextInspection }}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-container` as a dummy element (it will not produce any actual html tags) for the loop.
and then use `*ngIf` structural directive inside it, like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tags">
  <tr *ngIf="tag.id == tagged.id">
     <th>...</th>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

also if you need to reuse that kind of filtering you can create a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

it could look like this (simplistic example):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: Array<any>, prop: string, value: any) {
       return arr.filter(x => x[prop] && x[prop] === value);
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let tag of tags | filter:'id':tagged.id">
```

Comment: thanks, <ng-container> worked well.

I might start looking into pipes and try to get a feel for it.